# n-Torus with antipodal points identified

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

If we have n-torus $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1 \times ....$  n times, and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts on this just sending each component of $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1 \times ....$ to its antipodal. What will be the quotient space?

Comment: What is it for $n = 1$? For $n = 2$?

Comment: I thought about this. seems like sphere, but I am not sure

Comment: @sionn: Note that the space admits a two to one cover from the $n$-torus, so it cannot be sphere (except for $n=1$)